# becoming root in dockerfile for oracle container

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

I need to create the below directory in the oracle container as root but for some reason,the entire command is omitted. Any ideas why?

```
FROM oracle21c:21.3.0.0
USER root
RUN mkdir -p /u01/app/oracle
RUN oracle:oinstall /u01/app/oracle/
RUN chmod 775 /u01/app/oracle
```

thanks

Comment: Where is that oracle21c image coming from? Can't find it on Docker Hub.

Comment: It’s our repo on dockerhub. 
Any ideas on my issue?

Comment: Is it a private repo? Also what does "the entire command is omitted" mean? the `USER root` is omitted? The entire Dockerfile is omitted?

Comment: Sorry my poor grammar. I meant when running ‘docker-compose’ , it does not create the path as root user.